# How do I add additional controls to the Content of ModernButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I'm trying to put a `StackPanel` into a `ModernButton`. Here's the XAML:

```
<mui:ModernButton Margin="0,50"
              IconHeight="10"
              IconWidth="10"
              Background="#FF68217A"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Foreground="Black">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>George</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Washington</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

When I put this in place I get, "System.Windows.Controls.Stackpanel" displayed on the button. I don't understand why. The `ModernButton` is a child of the WPF `Button` class, and if replace `mui:ModernButton`, it works fine. (Of course you have to get rid of the IconHeight and IconWidth, but the point is that it works.)

So why don't my controls render properly inside of the `ModernButton`?

Comment: Man, this button is giving you all kinds of problems...lol. First the background and now this...j/k. Does it change anything if you use a textBox instead of a textblock?

Comment: Yes, it reliably changes if I use something like a blank, ol' WPF button.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ModernButton is just a poorly templated control.  I would submit a new issue to the [MUI project](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui).  Anyways, the proof is [here](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/1139513edc0b0d4de4e9efc90b66408cb09561fd/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared/Themes/ModernButton.xaml#L39) that the template won't get you very much besides displaying text.  What you're going to want to do is edit the template of the `ModernButton`. Right click a `ModernButton` in XAML designer > Edit Template > Edit a Copy... > OK > Go to XAML view.  In there you're going to want to do something like:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" >
    <!-- <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}"
               Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NullOrEmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=inverse}"
               Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ToLowerConverter}}"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
               Margin="4,-1,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/> -->
    <ContentPresenter Focusable="False"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
</Grid>
```

In short, you replace the `TextBlock` with a `ContentPresenter` and then you will be able to display whatever you want on your button.

Comment: That's what I tried at first, but that gave me the same behavior. :(

Comment: @Rod check out the updated answer. Turns out ModernButton's template just sucks.